# Mostrar barra de progreso con valores mientras se carga subpagina

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Tengo un preload o progress que muestro antes de ser redireccionado a otra página.

Lo que deseo es que mientras se está cargando para abrir otra página, el div del progress vaya aumentándose hasta el 100%, al igual que un valor numérico (n/100).

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```
var ajax_load = "<div class='progress'>" + "<div id='progress_id'   class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped active' " +
                    "role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='20' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 45%'>" +
                    "n/100</div></div>";

$("#menu_navegacion_inicio").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');        
        $("#subpagina").html(ajax_load).load(baseUrl + href, function () {
        });
    });
```

En ajax_load llamo al progress, pero necesito que el valor del atributo `aria-valuenow`, vaya aumentando hasta 100, y `n` también aumente hasta 100, donde n/100.

Me gustaría poder pasarle valores mientras se empieza cargar la página, indicando el tiempo de demora, que comienza desde 0% hasta 100%, una vez terminada la carga del progress, se abra la página que solicité.

Estaba pensando usar alguna iteración y pasarle algo como esto:

```
........
.....
var valeur= valeur +10;
........
$('#progress_id').css('width', valeur+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', valeur);  
$('#progress_id').append(valeur + '/100')
......
......
```

Pero no se como lo hago, si alguien sabe se lo agradecería bastante. No se si se entiende lo que expuse

Comment: Dale una mirada a esto: [ https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label ] si no te sirve seguimos investigando.

Comment: La pagina a la que estas redireccionado esta en el mismo _origen_ (protocolo, nombre de host y puerto) ? o es una pagina diferente, de otro sitio ?

Comment: la pagina está en el mismo sitio, es una subpagina, que recargo localmente dentro de un div. Similar a una vista parcial.

Comment: la idea es que en el progress, se vaya mostrando el incremento hasta llegar a 100%, finalizado esto, muestra la subpagina.

Comment: y este parcial que incluye, imagenes, audio, video ?

Comment: si, de todo, imagenes, video,

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos un ejemplo del parcial?, sobre todo como defines audios y videos, es importante para determinar si se han cargado ya los componentes. Por cierto, no agregues una respuesta, en cambio edita la pregunta para incluir este material.

Answer (score 7):

Puedes hacer algo como lo que se explica en esta [pregunta de StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668339/can-onprogress-functionality-be-added-to-jquery-ajax-by-using-xhrfields) o en la [página web de Dave Bond](http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/) (ambos enlaces en inglés). La idea es que la segunda versión de XMLHttpRequest incluye el evento `onprogress` que puedes escuchar y que te devolverá información interesante como por ejemplo:

- Cuál es el tamaño total de la descarga.
- Cuánto se ha descargado hasta ahora.
- El timestamp del momento en el que ocurre el evento.

Con los dos primeros puedes calcular el porcentaje completado (tamaño descargado / tamaño total) y con el segundo puedes calcular cuánto está tardando la descarga (timestamp del `onprogress` - timestamp de cuando se realizó la petición inicial).

Tendrías que cambiar el `load()` por `ajax()` pero eso no debería ser un problema. Aplicado a tu código el cambio se vería así:

```
var baseUrl = "";
var ajax_load = "<div class='progress'>" + "<div id='progress_id' class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped active' " +
                "role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='0' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 45%'>" +
                "n/100</div></div>";

$("#menu_navegacion_inicio").on("click", function(ev) {
  // estas dos lineas no cambian
  ev.preventDefault();
  var href = $(this).attr('href');

  // sustituir el contenido de subpagina con el mensaje de carga       
  $("#subpagina").html(ajax_load);

  // hacer llamada ajax al href
  $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + href,
    // cuando se completa la petición
    success: function(codigo){
      // rellenar la subpagina con el HTML obtenido
      $("#subpagina").html(codigo);
    },
    // modificar el valor de xhr a nuestro gusto
    xhr: function(){
      // obtener el objeto XmlHttpRequest nativo
      var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
      // añadirle un controlador para el evento onprogress
      xhr.onprogress = function(evt){ 
        // calculamos el porcentaje y nos quedamos sólo con la parte entera
        var porcentaje = Math.floor((evt.loaded/evt.total*100));
        // actualizamos el texto con el porcentaje mostrado
        $("#progress_id").text(porcentaje + "/100");
        // actualizamos la cantidad avanzada en la barra de progreso
        $("#progress_id").attr("aria-valuenow", porcentaje); 
        $("#progress_id").css("width", porcentaje + "%"); 
      };
      // devolvemos el objeto xhr modificado
      return xhr ;
    }
  });
});
```

---

Y aquí dejo un ejemplo de como funcionaría con la descarga de una imagen grande (2.75MB). Si ya has visto la imagen, puede que necesites limpiar la caché para poder ver la barra avanzar:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Onprogress</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <a id="menu_navegacion_inicio" href="https://i.imgur.com/Bq6ryBM.jpg">Click here</a>
    <div id="subpagina"></div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-7s5uDGW3AHqw6xtJmNNtr+OBRJUlgkNJEo78P4b0yRw= sha512-nNo+yCHEyn0smMxSswnf/OnX6/KwJuZTlNZBjauKhTK0c+zT+q5JOCx0UFhXQ6rJR9jg6Es8gPuD2uZcYDLqSw==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-KXn5puMvxCw+dAYznun+drMdG1IFl3agK0p/pqT9KAo= sha512-2e8qq0ETcfWRI4HJBzQiA3UoyFk6tbNyG+qSaIBZLyW9Xf3sWZHN/lxe9fTh1U45DpPf07yj94KsUHHWe4Yk1A==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      baseUrl = "";
      var ajax_load = "<div class='progress'>" + "<div id='progress_id' class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped active' " +
          "role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='0' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 0%'>" +
          "n/100</div></div>";

      $("#menu_navegacion_inicio").on("click", function(ev) {
        // estas dos lineas no cambian
        ev.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // sustituir el contenido de subpagina con el mensaje de carga       
        $("#subpagina").html(ajax_load);

        // hacer llamada ajax al href
        $.ajax({
          url: baseUrl + href,
          // cuando se completa la petición
          success: function(codigo){
            // rellenar la subpagina con el HTML obtenido
            $("#subpagina").html("COMPLETADO!");
          },
          // modificar el valor de xhr a nuestro gusto
          xhr: function(){
            // obtener el objeto XmlHttpRequest nativo
            var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
            // añadirle un controlador para el evento onprogress
            xhr.onprogress = function(evt){ 
              // calculamos el porcentaje y nos quedamos sólo con la parte entera
              var porcentaje = Math.floor((evt.loaded/evt.total*100));
              // actualizamos el texto con el porcentaje mostrado
              $("#progress_id").text(porcentaje + "/100");
              // actualizamos la cantidad avanzada en la barra de progreso
              $("#progress_id").attr("aria-valuenow", porcentaje); 
              $("#progress_id").css("width", porcentaje + "%"); 
            };
            // devolvemos el objeto xhr modificado
            return xhr ;
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: el problema con esta respuesta es que si el parcial tiene imágenes o audios (puede ser  pues es para personas con capacidades visuales disminuidas) no estarías tomando en cuenta el tiempo de carga de estas partes, pero estoy adivinando pues no contesto mis comentarios aun.

Comment: Cierto, se escribiría el HTML y si hay imágenes y otro contenido multimedia, se empezará a cargar después. En mi defensa, OP tendría el mismo problema con el `load`.

Comment: totalmente, por eso le pregunte antes de contestar, pues preparaba una respuesta muy parecida y me di cuenta que _quiza_ no es lo que OP necesita. Igual a la pregunta le falta contexto.

Comment: Disculpa @AlvaroMontoro, pero no soy muy bueno para ajax y jquery. ¿Como sería el controlador que tendría que añadirle para el evento onprogress?

Comment: @Danilo He editado la respuesta para que la función `xhr.onprogress` se ajuste más a lo que pusiste en los comentarios. Ahora `progress_id` mostrará el porcentaje de la forma n/100, y se actualizará su ancho para que coincida con el porcentaje descargado

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, Por ahora, reemplacé el codigo que me pusiste, pero no ocurre ningun cambio. No aumenta el progress.

Comment: @Danilo Corregí un error, faltaba un paréntesis y eso hacía que fallara todo. También, no añadí la variable `baseUrl` (aunque tendrás que cambiar el valor por el correcto). He probado el nuevo código y ahora funciona perfectamente. Perdón por la confusión y dime si te falla ahora

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Excelente, es lo que quería, pero ahora voy a probarlo, y te contaré como me fue.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, no se porque no me resulta, lo diferente es que no uso  $("#menu_navegacion_inicio").on("click", function(ev) { .....
sino que, $("#menu_navegacion_inicio").click(function (ev) {.....
porque no me aparece como subpagina dentro de otra de donde la llamo, sino como otra pagina individual.

Lo otro que estaba trantando de hacer por mientras, usando intervalos de tiempo, a medida que pasa el tiempo, se aumenta, lo hago de esta forma:

Comment: var progress = "<div class='progress'>" + "<div id='progress_id' class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped active' " +
                        "role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='0' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 0'>" +
                        "<span>" +  "0/100</span></div></div>";

Comment: var ajax_load_progress = function () {            
            $("#subpagina").append(progress);
            var stops = [25, 55, 85, 100];
            $.each(stops, function (index, value) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#progress_bar_id").css("width", value + "%").attr("aria-valuenow", value);
                }, index * 1500);
            });          

        };

Nota: var baseUrl = '<%= ResolveUrl("~/") %>';

Comment: Pero el $("#subpagina").append(progress); no funciona. No agrega el progress dentro del div subpagina, no se que pasa

Comment: se me olvido decir que, asi llamaría la carga cuando se carga una subpagina $("#menu_navegacion_inicio").click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('href');          
            $("#subpagina").html(ajax_load_progress).load(baseUrl + href, function () {
            });
        });

Comment: @Danilo He probado usando `.on("click"` y `.click(` con el código de arriba y funciona bien con ambos. Si `.on()` no funciona, podría ser porque estás usando una versión de jQuery antigua (se añadió en 1.7).

Comment: Sobre el resto de comentarios: el funcionamiento que describes en ellos no coincide del todo con el descrito en la pregunta. Esta respuesta hace que la barra de progreso avance de manera "progresiva", mientras que por los comentarios parece que quieres que suba a intervalos (25,55,85 y 100). Podrías modificar el código de arriba fácilmente para obtener ese comportamiento. Tan sólo tienes que comparar el porcentaje avanzado y actualizar la barra sii se ha sobrepasado alguno de esos valores (en lugar de con cada vez como yo hago arriba)

Comment: Montoro para presidente, siempre tiene todas las respuestas, en todos los temas :D

Answer (score 4):

Saludos, Hay un plugin muy bueno llamado **PACE**, que en lo personal me ha ayudado a no tener que desgastarme en este tipo de cosas y me permite concentrarme en lo realmente importante.

Este plugin se encarga de todo, es muy liviano y fácil de utilizar. Además, soporta bower y es opensource, puedes revisarlo aquí: http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/ el repo en GitHub es: https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/

Comment: mmm...se ve bueno, tendré que ver como lo adapto al codigo que expuse

Comment: como podría adapterse el plugin que me mostraste, para que se vaya mostrando, mientras se esta abriendo otra pagina.

Comment: Como podría adaptarlo con esto:

var ajax_load = function () {            

        var incremento = 0;
        var progress = "<div class='progress'>" + "<div id='progress_id' class='progress-bar progress-bar-striped active' " +
                    "role='progressbar' aria-valuenow='"+ incremento + "' aria-valuemin='0' aria-valuemax='100' style='width: 45%'>" +
                    "<span>" + incremento + "/100</span></div></div>";
        incremento=incremento +10;
        return progress; 
    };

Comment: $("#menu_navegacion_inicio").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $("#subpagina").html("");
        $("#subpagina").html(ajax_load).load(baseUrl + href, function () {
        });
    });

Comment: @Danilo te refieres al plugin "Pace"? creo que tu pregunta no es muy clara. Sobre todo cuando dices "mientras se esta abriendo otra pagina" ¿A que te refieres con eso?. Por otra parte, con el plugin no deberias tener que hacer nada adicional, el plugin se encarga de interceptar todas las llamadas ajax de la página (inluyendo el load de contenidos de otro recurso).

Comment: El plugin solo me saca el "loagind" cuando cargo la página, y hago llamadas ajax pero no me sale el loading :s

Comment: Estás utilizando alguna librería especial para la llamada ajax? se supone que el plugin intercepta todos los llamados XMLHttpRequest.